# How to display custom post meta in the appearance->menus page

Tags: menus, admin, post-meta

I'm working on a website and added a custom meta option for all pages / posts called: "Location".

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_privacy_location', true );
```

I'd like to add the value on the menu item in: Appearance->Menus so my client can see what pages have which location !

Can't figure out what hook to use ! Help plz :)

Comment: Try this: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this for the Menu, not the pages / posts

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood. Thought you meant 'admin menu', despite you clearly saying "apperances->menu".

Answer (score 3):

The menu items boxes are created by the class `Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit` in   wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php.

Thus to alter those boxes you'll have to make your custom Walker I guess.

But if you mean adding the new value to the nav menu meta-boxes (the boxes to the left side of the page) this will do the job:

The function that adds new meta_boxes:

```
function my_function() {
   add_meta_box( 'foo', __( 'Fooo' ), 'callback_function' , 'nav-menus', 'side', 'default' );
}

The callback that renders the output for the new boxes:

function callback_function( ) {
  global $wp_meta_boxes;
  var_dump($wp_meta_boxes);
}
```

And you can use both:

```
add_filter( 'manage_nav-menus_columns', 'my_function');
```

or

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_function');
```